# Trying to get all numerical values and periods form string

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql, sql-server-2005

There's data I'm trying to retrieve using a SELECT statement which is input by various people in regards to an amount in grams. As there doesnt seem to be a standard here are some of the ways people have written it:

- 200g
- 0.2KG
- 0.200kg
- 0.2
- 0.2g(e)
- 2KG
- .222

I currently have this function below that returns all numerical characters into an NVARCHAR which I could then CONVERT into a decimal to use in calculations.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_GetNumeric]
(@strAlphaNumeric VARCHAR(256))
RETURNS VARCHAR(256)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @intAlpha INT
SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric)
BEGIN
WHILE @intAlpha > 0
BEGIN
SET @strAlphaNumeric = STUFF(@strAlphaNumeric, @intAlpha, 1, '' )
SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric )
END
END
RETURN ISNULL(@strAlphaNumeric,0)
END
```

This does work fine in some cases but, for an example, any data that's written like "0.2..." turns into a "2" which whilst working with grams and Kilograms isn't helpful.

I need it to output either to a DECIMAL or NVARCHAR and to keep the decimal place location so a 0.2 stays as a 0.2 and a 0.200 stays as such .

(letters are only ever at the start or end never inbetween the numbers, it does sometimes start with a `.`)

Comment: Are you *really* still using SQL Server 2005? It's way outside of support now. The better question, however, is why are you storing numerical data as a `varchar` and not as a numerical data type (even your function returns a `varchar`).

Comment: Its being transferred to 2012 very soon i believe, its not a server we use very often at all but yeah its an old one haha! Because when its originally stored that's just the format that is used, unfortunately i don't have any way to change that.

It returns varchar because that's the datatype at the end, like i said, it doesnt create any bother with it staying like a varchar at all, thats not the issue.

Comment: But why was it originally stored as a `varchar`? As you're finding out, bad data type choices are always a problem. Unfortunately, any solutions I can think of would only work on SQL Server 2008+. Like I said, 2005 is way out of support now, so any upgrades should really have been completed already. Why are you only going to 2012 as well? That's out of support as well (it's only in extended). Only SQl Server 2014 - 2017 are fully supported at the moment.

Comment: Because originally we didnt have a need to manipulate the numbers. I believe it was an electronic form that only had a text field so when people entered in a number it was down to user preference on how they wrote it. Don't get me wrong, i know thats not a good way to have it at all, but this is what ive got to work with and i cant go thoruhg and manually change them all and then change the data type, theres way to much data to do that.

I don't think its been fully decided as of yet what version we're moving to for that particular server, its not a decision i get to be involved in.

Comment: @A.Cassin you probably *shouldn't* migrate to 2012 as it's *already* out of mainstream support. Installing an old version doesn't mean you avoid bugs. It means you get *all* of the bugs that were fixed in later versions. And end up requiring a more expensive license too. [Since 2016 SP1 features](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/11/sql-server-2016/big-deal-sp1) that were available only in Enterprise editions are available even in Express, including compression, in-memory tables, partitioning etc

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Again, it's not really a decision I get to choose. I have no idea what licenses they have or haven't got. Sadly, I've got to work with what I've got

Comment: @A.Cassin you can't buy what isn't available for sale. Even if you want to downgrade, you have to pay the *current* price. You should probably erm ... mention to whoever makes the decision that there's a [page with the support lifecycle of ever product](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search/1044).

Comment: I don't know if they already hold licenses already or anything, but we already have servers on 2012 so i assume they do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find some char that is not used, and replace `.0` with it. Then put it back:

```
 BEGIN

DECLARE @intAlpha INT

    SET @strAlphaNumeric = REPLACE(@strAlphaNumeric, '.0', '#');
    SET @strAlphaNumeric = REPLACE(@strAlphaNumeric, '0.', '##');
    SET @strAlphaNumeric = REPLACE(@strAlphaNumeric, '.', '###');

    SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9#]%', @strAlphaNumeric)

    WHILE @intAlpha > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @strAlphaNumeric = STUFF(@strAlphaNumeric, @intAlpha, 1, '' )
        SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9#]%', @strAlphaNumeric )
    END

    SET @strAlphaNumeric = REPLACE(@strAlphaNumeric, '###', '.')
    SET @strAlphaNumeric = REPLACE(@strAlphaNumeric, '##', '0.');
    SET @strAlphaNumeric = REPLACE(@strAlphaNumeric, '#', '.0');

SELECT ISNULL(@strAlphaNumeric,0)
END
```

or just add the `.` like this:

```
PATINDEX('%[^0-9.]%', @strAlphaNumeric)
```

but you will have issue if you have string like this: `te....st 5.0 kg`, so it will be better just to replace `.0` with something special.

Note, in the example I am replacing with `#` but you can replace with five of them in order to make the value more unique - `#####`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

String parsing in T-SQL is always challenging.  But with this situation, SUBSTRING might be easier.

You mentioned this:  *letters are only ever at the start or end never inbetween the numbers*

So basically we just need to find where the number starts and ends in the string.

Have a look at this:

```
DECLARE @String NVARCHAR(100)

SET @String = 'This is k.g. or g it''s .0456 not g'

SELECT PATINDEX('%[0-9 ].%[0-9]%', @String ) --Where is the first occurance of a number
SELECT PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(@String)) --Flip the string and tell me from the other end where that number occurs
SELECT LEN(@String) - PATINDEX('%[0-9 ].%[0-9]%', REVERSE(@String)) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @String ) +2 --substract those from the length and add 2, tells me how long it is.

--The above is basically where the number starts and it's length in the string.
--Then use substring to pull it all out.
SELECT SUBSTRING(@String, PATINDEX('%[0-9 ].%[0-9]%', @String ), LEN(@String) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(@String)) - PATINDEX('%[0-9 ].%[0-9]%', @String ) +2)

--larger sample set
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #TestData

CREATE TABLE #TestData (
NumberData NVARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO #TestData (
                          [NumberData]
                      )
VALUES
('200g')
,('0.2KG')
,('0.200kg')
,('0.2')
,('0.2g(e)')
,('0.2000000k.g.')
,('grams 0.345')
,('This is k.g. 0.456 not g')
,('.456kg')

SELECT *, SUBSTRING([NumberData], PATINDEX('%[0-9 ].%[0-9]%', [NumberData] ), LEN([NumberData]) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE([NumberData])) - PATINDEX('%[0-9 ].%[0-9]%', [NumberData] ) +2)FROM #TestData
```

Comment: Not entirely sure, but its having an issue running that. Say's theres incorrect syntax at the location `,('0.2KG')`

Comment: @A.Cassin Sorry I don't see it.  I just copied and pasted my example back out and ran it with no error.

Comment: @A.Cassin oh wait, my bad, you're 2005 and this example is using a table variable which wasn't until 2008.  I'll update so have a working example.